# No data in Icinga-web

Tags: php, monitoring, redhat, nagios

I'am trying to get Icinga-web to work properly.

I followed the following tutorial: https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/Setting+up+Icinga+Web+on+RHEL

**This works:**

- Icinga classic web interface is working perfect. (This also means ido2db is working fine)
- The hosts and services are showing on the top of Icinga-web interface.
- The notifications in Icinga-web are working (Incl new events)
- Apache, Icinga and Ido2db are not showing any errors in the logs. (including full debug)

**This is NOT working:**

When I request data in Icinga-web I get => No data.
Except for the tab notifications, they are showing.

**The server configuration:**

- Redhat 6.x enterprise:  2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64
- Postgresql: PostgreSQL 8.4.13 compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4), 64-bit
- Icinga: v1.7.2

I did some extra testing using the following tutorial.  But I didn't find any problems => https://wiki.icinga.org/display/testing/Icinga+IDOUtils+Testing

Does anyone have a similar problem ?

If not => how would you debug a problem like this ?

Thanks Ilias

Comment: maybe you can check on this link :

http://serverfault.com/questions/334070/icinga-web-doesnt-update-when-i-change-configuration